# Two MySQL SELECT queries in one

Tags: php, mysql, extjs

I'm working on an Extjs application and I need to get the result of two select queries, encode the results in Json then bind the store containing these results to a gridview.

I have a gridview whith two columns, the first one is "name_scope" and the second is a combobox that should contain the values of the scope (a scope can have multiple values). So I've created two tables in mySQL, "scope" and "scope_value", I want to bind scope_name from "scope" table to my first column, then value(s) from "scope_value" table to the combo column.

I don't think it's a good idea to make two stores for this matter, so I want to make only one php script that would contain these two queries :

```
SELECT name_scope FROM scope
```

AND

```
SELECT value FROM value_scope WHERE name_scope = "'. $name_scope .'"';
```

These are my tables :

```
create table scope (name_scope varchar(50) not null primary key, description varchar(100));
create table value_scope (id_value int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,name_scope varchar(50), value varchar(100), 
            foreign key (name_scope) references scope(name_scope) on delete cascade);
```

My gridview :

```
{
    xtype: 'container',
    id : 'grid_container',

    anchor: '100%',
     forceFit: true,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        id: 'scope_grid',
        layout : 'fit',
        frame: true,
        columnLines: true,
        iconCls: 'icon-grid',
        title: 'Prod/Rel added',
        store: 'GetScopeData',
        columns: [{
            id: 'n_scope',
            text: 'Scope',
            flex: 1,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'name_scope'},

           { header: 'Product Release',
            width: 220,
            fixed: true,
            hideable: false,
            dataIndex: 'value',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                displayField: 'value',
                valueField: 'value',
                mode: 'local',
        editable : false,
                typeAhead: false,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                lazyRender: true,
                emptyText: 'Select action',
                listClass: 'x-combo-list-small'

            }}
]}
```

What should my php script look like?
Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can combile these two select statement into one, like

```
SELECT value FROM value_scope WHERE name_scope in (SELECT name_scope FROM scope);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make one store with the result set you want - 2 fields (name_scope and value) and combine your query to one using join:

```
SELECT scope.name_scope,value  FROM scope
INNER JOIN value_scope ON(scope.name_scope = value_scope.name_scope)
WHERE scope.name_scope = "'. $name_scope .'"';
```